# center button/text in table cell

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a table in the `.aspx` file like this

```
 <asp:Table ID="tblRoles" runat="server" GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="center" Style="margin-top: 1em; margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em;">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow ForeColor="White" BackColor="DodgerBlue" Style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #6688FF, #AACCFF); height: 4em; text-align: center; text-transform: capitalize;">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="one"/>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="two" width="10%"/>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="three" width="10%"/>
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
</asp:Table>
```

In the `cs` file the code that populates the table includes text and buttons. For example,

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
            TableCell cellEdit = new TableCell();
            Button btnEdit = new Button();
            btnEdit.Text = "Edit";
            btnEdit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return btnEditClick();");
            cellEdit.Controls.Add(btnEdit);
```

The table is formatted nicely on the page but the elements inside each cell is aligned to the left. Is there any way to get the content centered within the table?

Comment: You can use css for this purpose

Comment: Can you add in the html that's output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `text-align: center` to the Table Style tag:

```
<asp:Table ID="tblRoles" runat="server" GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="center" Style="margin-top: 1em; margin-left:1em; margin-right:1em; text-align: center;">
```

Or if at all possible, do this in the site's CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, give `table td { text-align: center; }`